# Comparing timeofday with datetime stored in DB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am working on a project, which records the login time of employees.
Shifts have been defined with starting time and ending time (stored in DB to DateTime field)
from DateTimePicker.value (it also stores date with time, which is unnecessary)

When employee logs in, I need to check if he is intime or late etc.
I am comparing it in the following way

```
If TimeOfDay >= DateTime.Parse(DsReadShift.tblShift.Rows(0).Item("StartTime")) And DateTime.Now <= DateTime.Parse(DsReadShift.tblShift.Rows(0).Item("EndTime")) Then 
            vrStatus = "Logged In"
```

End If

But it does not work.  I assume there should be some way to ignore date associated and only time should be compare.  But I do not know how.

Am I storing time in right way in the DB?

Please advise.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Haven't got a lot of time... but try this out first.

```
Dim vStart = DateTime.Parse(DsReadShift.tblShift.Rows(0).Item("StartTime"))
Dim vEnd = DateTime.Parse(DsReadShift.tblShift.Rows(0).Item("EndTime"))

If TimeOfDay >= vStart.TimeOfDay And DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay <= vEnd.TimeOfDay Then 
    vrStatus = "Logged In"
End If
```

Be tidier in your 'equations' and they become easier to read and debug!